# Replace Object[][] Array with custom input

Tags: java, jframe

I am new to building GUI's in java and I'm currently making a JTable. Now in the Oracle documentation it uses an object array that looks like this:

```
Object[][] data = {
    {"Kathy", "Smith",
     "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
    {"John", "Doe",
     "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Sue", "Black",
     "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
    {"Jane", "White",
     "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Joe", "Brown",
     "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
};
```

I am not sure how to translate this into a loop of objects to fill what I need.
Aka like

```
for(User u: userList) {
Object [1] = u.getID;
//Etc
}
```

Edit: **Note** That the columns are already created in a String array, I just am trying to populate them with an array of objects, and I am not sure how to replace what Oracle documentation has given me with my own object array (that contains things like ID, Name, Address, etc) instead of the first codebocks details.

Comment: You have to use nested loop - one for creating rows, second one for creating columns :)

Comment: I dont think you understood the question, I am not asking about rows and columns

Comment: What means "translate this into a loop" ?

Comment: As in, instead of using pre-written items in an Object[][] array I want to input my own items from my own Array into an Object[][] array.

Answer (score 0):

This is code for Oracle's example

```
    Object[][] data = new Object[users.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        User user = users[i];

        data[i] = new Object[5];
        data[i][0] = user.getName();
        data[i][1] = user.getSurname();
        data[i][2] = user.getSport();
        data[i][3] = user.getYear();
        data[i][4] = user.getVegetarian();
    }
}
```

For the code above the user is class:

```
class User {
  private String name;
  private String surname;
  // other fields 

  public String getName() { return this.name; }
  // other geters
}
```